# How rewrite the matrix to page's size?

Tags: formatting, matrices

I have a big matrices like below:

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
\left[ \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
-\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
\frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
\frac{1729}{491520} & \frac{10163}{61440} & \frac{1929}{8192} & -\frac{529}{1920} & \frac{33777}{163840} & -\frac{277}{12288} & \vdots & \frac{15}{8} & -\frac{5}{4} & \frac{3}{8} \\
\frac{271}{52488} & \frac{1616}{6561} & \frac{1613}{4374} & -\frac{2720}{6561} & \frac{205}{648} & -\frac{230}{6561} & \vdots & \frac{20}{9} & -\frac{16}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \\
\frac{11}{1200} & \frac{67}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\frac{11}{1200} & \frac{167}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
\frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
-\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4}
\end{array} \right].
\end{equation*}
```

**Question.** Could someone give an idea how to resize the matrix? I need decrease the size on 1.5 in.

Comment: Using a smaller font, perhaps?

Comment: Well, you can scale any box content using `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package. You might need to wrap it into a `minipage` or `varwidth` (`varwidth` package) environment if the content contains line breaks etc. There is also my `adjustbox` package which simplifies this all, e.g. `\begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\linewidth,center,width=\linewidth}\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}\end{adjustbox}`. **HOWEVER**, scaling text is normally bad because the font is not designed to get scaled down, but rather has different figures for different sizes. So scaling font size should be tried first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\bsmallmatrix` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% Loaded by mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \left[ \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
      -\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
      \frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
      \frac{1729}{491520} & \frac{10163}{61440} & \frac{1929}{8192} & -\frac{529}{1920} & \frac{33777}{163840} & -\frac{277}{12288} & \vdots & \frac{15}{8} & -\frac{5}{4} & \frac{3}{8} \\
      \frac{271}{52488} & \frac{1616}{6561} & \frac{1613}{4374} & -\frac{2720}{6561} & \frac{205}{648} & -\frac{230}{6561} & \vdots & \frac{20}{9} & -\frac{16}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \\
      \frac{11}{1200} & \frac{67}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
      \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
      \frac{11}{1200} & \frac{167}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
      \frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
      -\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4}
    \end{array} \right].
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bsmallmatrix}
      0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \vdots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
      -\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} \\
      \frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
      \frac{1729}{491520} & \frac{10163}{61440} & \frac{1929}{8192} & -\frac{529}{1920} & \frac{33777}{163840} & -\frac{277}{12288} & \vdots & \frac{15}{8} & -\frac{5}{4} & \frac{3}{8} \\
      \frac{271}{52488} & \frac{1616}{6561} & \frac{1613}{4374} & -\frac{2720}{6561} & \frac{205}{648} & -\frac{230}{6561} & \vdots & \frac{20}{9} & -\frac{16}{9} & \frac{5}{9} \\
      \frac{11}{1200} & \frac{67}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
      \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
      \frac{11}{1200} & \frac{167}{150} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{56}{75} & \frac{243}{400} & -\frac{1}{5} & \vdots & 3 & -3 & 1 \\
      \frac{5723}{20160} & \frac{8}{7} & -\frac{3809}{1680} & \frac{788}{105} & -\frac{14823}{2240} & \frac{1201}{1260} & \vdots & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
      -\frac{5039}{201600} & -\frac{313}{1575} & \frac{347}{1120} & -\frac{1622}{1575} & \frac{20331}{22400} & -\frac{47}{360} & \vdots & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4}
    \end{bsmallmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mathtools provides pre fenced versions of smallmatrix